# Norman Spinrad novel from the point of view of a senile dictator?

Tags: story-identification

I once looked at an old science fiction novel; I think it was by Norman Spinrad. It was told from the stream-of-consciousness point of view of a senile dictator of the USA. It didn't have any chapters, only page breaks.

Comment: How old? Can you narrow it down to a decade or two? I guess it was set it the future — how far in the future? How advanced was the technology? Like Star Trek, or more or less like today? Did it have space colonies, matter transmission, life extension, AI robots? Was the dictator male or female?

Comment: 60s or 70s, I think. Dictator was male. I suspect it was set in the near future--a matter of decades, not centuries.

Comment: Decades you say?

Comment: I have read quite a lot of Spinrad novels and know the plots of most of those I haven't read (I interviewed him about 10 years ago and had to read up on his works), but that one doesn't ring a bell. I suspect it is another writer you're looking for.